# How "Run time Polymorphism or Overriding" works?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, overriding, runtime

I know what overriding is. As overriding is run-time polymorphism it works during run-time. But everything seems compile-time to me as the code works after the compiling phase. Can you help me to visualize the run-time polymorphism that how it decides during run-time?

Comment: Please don't `format` prose with `code blocks`.

Answer (score 2):

Run-time polymorphism work base on `vtable` & `vpointer` concept. For more detail, please see [this article](https://pabloariasal.github.io/2017/06/10/understanding-virtual-tables/)

Answer (score 1):

For C++ "Run time" polymorphism, read [this post](https://www.go4expert.com/articles/virtual-table-vptr-t16544/)